# Fail to decrypt Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption

I got an error Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher when trying to decrypt my encrypted message.

What I encrypt is this:

```
{
    "guid": "d123-231s-2314w123-21312-2312312",
    "userid": "000123",
    "channel": "TESTINGCHANNELTEST"
}
```

but when I decrypt it I got that error. But when I decrypt this message

```
{
    "guid": "00",
    "userid": "00",
    "channel": "TEST"
}
```

It works.

What make this issue?
Heres my code to encrypt and decrypt:

```
public class EncryptDecryptModel {

        private static final String key = "aesEncryptionKey";
        private static final String initVector = "encryptionIntVec";

        public static String encrypt(String value) {
            try {
                IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

                byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
                return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static String decrypt(String encrypted) {
            try {
                IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
                byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted));
                //original = Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted);

                return new String(original);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

This is to encrypt:

```
@PostMapping("/getEncrypt")
public String getEncrypt(@RequestBody OpenMediaModel openMediaModel) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    EncryptDecryptModel encryptDecryptModel=new EncryptDecryptModel();
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    String message = openMediaModel.getGuid() + "|" + openMediaModel.getCif()
            + "|" + openMediaModel.getChannel();
    byte[] encodedhash = digest.digest(
            message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    message = message + "|" + new String(encodedhash);
    return  encryptDecryptModel.encrypt(message);
}
```

And this is how I decrypt my message:

```
 @GetMapping("/getDecrypt")
    public String getDecrypt(@RequestParam String encrypt) throws NoSuchPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException {
        EncryptDecryptModel encryptDecryptModel=new EncryptDecryptModel();
        String plainMessage = encryptDecryptModel.decrypt(encrypt);
        String[] splitMessage = plainMessage.split("\\|");
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        String message = splitMessage[0] + "|" + splitMessage[1]
                + "|" + splitMessage[2];

        //byte[] encodedhash = digest.digest(
          //      message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        //return new String(encodedhash).equals(splitMessage[3]);
        return splitMessage[0]+"-"+splitMessage[1]+"-"+splitMessage[2];
    }
```

The Issue is when I put long json format like the first one, I got exception:

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple
>   of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Sorry this is my first time do this encrypt. So got no clue when I decrypt long message. since It work well when I do short message. and I tried use that decodeBase64 but no value
Need help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Both encryption and decryption seem to work. But you should specify an encoding for the plaintext in `encrypt` and `decrypt` (analogous to key and IV). It seems to be JSON-data. How do you generate the plaintext to be encrypted from these data? Possibly there is a conversion bug. Have you tried to encrypt a simple string? Please post the _complete_ code including the calls with the _real_ plaintext to be encrypted.

Comment: There is an obvious first step - verify that the input for the decrypt is a multiplum of 16. Please show the input for the decrypt.

Comment: @Topaco I ma able to decrypt the second request. I'll try to encrypt and decript a string

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen this is the request to be decrypt s5VMAS9K5fIHEV/+3uhX2UIfUCCdo9Y+RKLboVByAcn40pOjFpWoF8BxB5IFip3KAIO0les8QCoQwldL3RBeLyx0S6QBc1wuAxRNJ5mvX5vECpMbQaAF5/4ACDyW7XeWdYGxPp0hPVQmeMevz24vSAXQQ/ZRGWl62u8mljkK0NU=

Comment: The ciphertext can be decrypted on my machine with UTF-8 to `d123-231s-2314w123-21312-2312312|null|TESTINGCHANNELTEST|a3?)d$i/?DF?1?Zx?2??F????????????????????` It could be a problem not directly related to encryption/decryption. I would like to be able to understand how you pass the posted data to the `encrypt`-method, as well as what happens to the data after decryption. Thus again, post a _complete_ executable code that causes the problem on your machine.

Comment: @Topaco updated. Haven't try to decrypt single string yet. I'll update the info soon.

Comment: The data you have posted and the data you have decrypted have _different_ formats. Obviously, there's a conversion process before encryption. Perhaps the issue is here. Thus, analyze this part of the code in particular and check the plaintext _immediately_ before encryption.

Comment: @Topaco did u meant that sha256ml?  sorry, ignore the sha256. But ill try to encrypt without sha256 in the plain message. Then decrypt it

Comment: Can you post the `getDecrypt`-counterpart for encryption? Alternatively check in some way if the data are not already corrupted when you pass them to the `encrypt`-method.

Comment: @Topaco posted bro. Thanks for your help

Comment: (1) In `getEncrypt` the hash of the message is determined and stored in a string. This storage corrupts this part of the data. One possibility would be to encode the hash before concatenating, e.g. `hexadecimal: message += "|" + Hex.encodeHexString(encodedhash);`. (2) Apart from this problem, I can decrypt the posted ciphertext with the posted key/IV on my machine. This ciphertext has Base64 decoded a length of 128 bytes and shouldn't therefore throw the exception you observed (128/16 = 8). Does `getDecrypt` for _this_ posted ciphertext really fail on your machine (using the posted key/IV)?